# Symfony Assetic less filter fails

Tags: symfony, less, assetic

I am trying to set the assetic less filter up in a symfony 2.7 project.
I am working on macOSX.

my config.yml

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        less:
            node: %node_bin%
            node_paths: [%node_modules%,/usr/bin]
            apply_to: "\.less$"
```

When I try `php app/console assetic:dump` this is the error I get

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                                                           
  An error occurred while running:                                                                              
  '/usr/local/bin/node' '/private/var/folders/cf/kkbc91t52jbds1tyy3z4_4s00000gn/T/assetic_lessK4Mc8v'           
  Error Output:                                                                                                 
  /usr/bin/less:1                                                                                               
  (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ����                                           
                                                                ^                                               
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL                                                                         
      at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)                                                          
      at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)                                                                     
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)                                                       
      at Module.load (module.js:458:32)                                                                         
      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)                                                                       
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)                                                                
      at Module.require (module.js:468:17)                                                                      
      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)                                                                     
      at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/cf/kkbc91t52jbds1tyy3z4_4s00000gn/T/assetic_lessK4Mc8v:1:74)  
      at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)                                                                     
  Input:                                                                                                        
  // This less file is empty
```

I tried with an empty less file to sure the error was not during compiling. I also tried `lessc myfile.less`and it works.

I don't understand what the error could be and what I should be looking at next. Ant help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the `node_paths` parameter

I changed it from

```
node_paths: [/Users/benomite/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules,/usr/bin]
```

to

```
node_paths: [/Users/benomite/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules]
```

Seems there were a conflict here, but I have to admit I have no idea why.